# How to read sdcard/pendrive from windows desktop application using flutter?

Tags: flutter, desktop-application, usb-drive, flutter-windows

Windows desktop application : Have to read sdcard/pendrive/usb drive using flutter code for windows application

Comment: Try using this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/quick_usb

Comment: Thanks @JustaPerson! I tried this already but it somehow does not gives path for USB and it shows exception on many features - tested in windows machine.